# Interpretation of AUC NaN values in h2o cross-validation predictions summary

Tags: r, cross-validation, h2o, glm, auc

I have noticed that for some runs of:

```
train=as.h2o(u)
mod = h2o.glm(family= "binomial", x= c(1:15), y="dc",  
       training_frame=train, missing_values_handling = "Skip",
       lambda = 0, compute_p_values = TRUE, nfolds = 10,
       keep_cross_validation_predictions= TRUE)
```

there are NaNs in cross-validation metrics summary of AUC for some cv iterations of the model.

For example:

```
print(mod@model$cross_validation_metrics_summary["auc",])
```

Cross-Validation Metrics Summary:

```
          mean         sd cv_1_valid cv_2_valid cv_3_valid cv_4_valid cv_5_valid cv_6_valid cv_7_valid cv_8_valid cv_9_valid cv_10_valid

auc 0.63244045 0.24962118       0.25  0.6666667  0.8095238        1.0  0.6666667 0.46666667        NaN        NaN        1.0         0.2
```

NaN in CV seems to appear less frequently when I set smaller nfolds=7.

How these NaN values should be interpreted and when h2o cross-validation outputs them?

I suppose it happens when AUC can't be assessed correctly in an iteration. My training set has 70 complete rows.

Can such AUC cross-validation results (containing NaNs) be considered as reliable?

Comment: is it possible for you to post a fully reproducible code snippet? so that we can try and reproduce what you are seeing. thanks!

Comment: Did you normalize data ?

Comment: My input data frame is quite simple and isn't scaled: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UiIkxlHCq1tJZNOH6hQD30gEMaPdmhgh/view?usp=sharing] You will get 3 NaNs if you set seed = 1234 in h2o.glm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are specific cases that could cause division by zero when calculating the ROC curve, which could cause an AUC to be NaN. It's probable that due to small data you have some folds that have no true positives and are causing this issue.

We can test this by keeping the fold column and then counting the values of dc in each fold:

```r
...

train <- as.h2o(u)
mod <- h2o.glm(family = "binomial"
              , x = c(1:15)
              , y = "dc"
              , training_frame = train
              , missing_values_handling = "Skip"
              , lambda = 0
              , compute_p_values = TRUE
              , nfolds = 10
              , keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment = TRUE
              , seed = 1234)

fold <- as.data.frame(h2o.cross_validation_fold_assignment(mod))
df <- cbind(u,fold)

table(df[c("dc","fold_assignment")])

   fold_assignment
dc  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  0 4 6 6 2 9 6 6 4 4 6
  1 2 2 3 4 0 2 0 0 1 2

mod@model$cross_validation_metrics_summary["auc",]

Cross-Validation Metrics Summary: 
          mean         sd cv_1_valid cv_2_valid cv_3_valid cv_4_valid cv_5_valid cv_6_valid cv_7_valid
auc 0.70238096 0.19357596      0.875  0.6666667        0.5      0.375        NaN  0.5833333        NaN
    cv_8_valid cv_9_valid cv_10_valid
auc        NaN        1.0   0.9166667
```

We see that the folds with NaN are the same folds that have only dc=0.

Not counting the NaN, the wide variety of AUC for your folds (from 0.2 to 1) tells us that this is not a robust model, and it is likely being overfitted. Can you add more data?

Comment: I can't add more data, so I try to deal with it ;) Moreover target variable isn't balanced (60 : 19).
I tried to run GBM 100x and received mean AUC=0.56 (sd=0.07) and MSE=0.25. Data download link should be correct now.

Comment: Indeed, the folds without positives have AUC equal to NaN. I set also balance_classes=TRUE in GBM but the AUC metrics didn't get better.